# strcmp() возвращает неверные значения

Tags: c++, winapi

Код, приведенный ниже, запрашивает ввод двух строк через *WinAPI* и сравнивает их через `strcmp()`.
Результат всегда получается неверный.
Я еще не имею достаточно знаний в *C++*, чтобы найти проблему самостоятельно, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

```
#define CONSOLE_ENDLINE "\r\n"
void ConsoleWrite(char* c)
{
    HANDLE cHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    LPDWORD numberOfCharsWritten = nullptr;
    WriteConsole(cHandle, c, strlen(c), numberOfCharsWritten, NULL);
}

void ConsoleWrite(const char* c)
{
    HANDLE cHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    LPDWORD numberOfCharsWritten = nullptr;
    WriteConsole(cHandle, c, strlen(c), numberOfCharsWritten, NULL);
}

char* ConsoleReadLine()
{
    HANDLE hStdIn;
    TCHAR lpszString[120];
    DWORD ToRead = 120, Read;

    hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
    ReadConsole(hStdIn, lpszString, ToRead, &Read, NULL);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
    ConsoleWrite("\r\n");

    if (lpszString[Read - 2] == '\r')
    {
        lpszString[Read - 2] = '\0';
    }

    if (lpszString[Read - 1] == '\n')
    {
        lpszString[Read - 1] = '\0';
    }

    return static_cast<char*>(lpszString);
}

void check() {
    ConsoleWrite("Welcome! Please log in!\r\n");
    ConsoleWrite("Enter login: ");
    char* login = ConsoleReadLine();
    ConsoleWrite("Enter password: ");
    char* password = ConsoleReadLine();

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Login strcmp: " << strcmp(login, "admin") << CONSOLE_ENDLINE;
    ss << "Password strcmp: " << strcmp(password, "adminp") << CONSOLE_ENDLINE;
    ConsoleWrite(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

На деле выдает `1` либо `-1`, если во введенной строке есть пробелы.

```
Welcome! Please log in!
Enter login: admin
Enter password: notadminp
Login strcmp: 1
Password strcmp: 1
```

Я проверял, что считывает `ReadConsole()`, результаты оказались верными.
 Функция работает правильно. Тут я встал в ступор.
Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Вы бы посмотрели в отладчике, действительно ли строки одинаковые.

Comment: ConsoleReadLine возвращает указатель на локальный буфер, которого уже нет после вызова функции. Так делать нельзя.

Comment: >Так делать нельзя. И как же мне поступить в этом случае? Что возвращать?

Comment: У Вас в тегах стоит c++ вот и используйте этот язык. А если желаете программировать на c, то для работы со строками необходимо выделить заранее буфер необходимой длины. Обычно длину берут с запасом. После считывания строки, можно создать новый буфер необходимой длины, данные скопировать, старый буфер уничтожить. Безболезненный способ изменить Ваш код - создавать буфер в check() и передавать указатель на него в ConsoleReadLine(). Последняя не должна использовать локальный буфер, а исключительно созданный извне.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @sba Что касается `string`... В данном конкретном случае использование `string` только для сравнения двух строк, которые получаются вызовами API через `char*`, мне представляется слишком расточительным...

Comment: @Harry, если смотреть на вопрос с этой точки зрения, то конечно же - да. Но если задуматься, что это сравнение будет происходить только единожды или условно очень редко, то выгоды от такого рода оптимизаций никакой, а головная боль в будущем обеспечена. Резюмирую - если используете C++, то и используйте его вовсю, переходя на более низкоуровневые средства только там где это действительно оправдано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В языке C++ для работы со строками предусмотрен тип [std:: string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). Вместо использования нуль-терминальных си-строк лучше использовать преимущества именно C++ строк. При таком подходе многие проблемы отпадут сами собой.

Независимо от вышесказанного, у Вас наблюдается более глобальная проблема. В языке C++ локальные переменные создаются на стеке. После покидания области видимости такой переменной, она уничтожается, а освободившаяся стековая память немедленно будет использована для других локальных переменных. Другими словами нельзя возвращать из функции и позже использовать ни ссылку ни указатель на любую локальную переменную созданную внутри этой функции.

Вам необходимо создать извне буфер для хранения си-строки. Это можно сделать в функции check(), идентичным способом как это сделано в ConsoleReadLine() или любым другим удобным способом, например используя функцию malloc(size_t size). Далее следует просто передать в качестве аргумента функции ConsoleReadLine() указатель на этот буфер. Последняя просто считает в него необходимые данные, аналогично как она это делает сейчас.